SQL group but return wrong result
I have a table:



name
code




a
1


a
2


b
1


b
2


c
2


c
3



want to get this result where code =1 and group by name



name
code




a
1


a
2


b
1


b
2



I tried this query:
select name, code where code=1 and group by name , code

but I just get this:



name
code




a
1


b
1



How can I fix it to get the correct results?

Why would you expect to get results where code is 2, when you've got "where code=1"?

You edits are confusing and difficult to understand what you want. At any rate, you are missing FROM in your query.

I do want to group by name where name with code =1 and any name have code = 1 then the other code should show up

Use a subquery or CTE.

The desired results are ordering/sorting by name, rather than grouping by name

What RDBMS do you use?

Which values are possible as code? NULL, negative values, is this a varchar or integer column? Can the same code appear more than once per same name? Would this matter? I think your question is still very vague. Maybe the answer is correct, maybe not, you should improve the question.

You appear to want all of the records for names that contain a code = 1
SELECT *
FROM Example 
WHERE name in
(SELECT name from Example WHERE Code='1')

fiddle
CTE version as suggested by Isolated
WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE WHERE Code='1'
)
SELECT E.*
FROM CTE C
INNER JOIN Example E ON C.name=E.name 


Excellent. Thank you so much.

@mike  it's better to vote up and mark the answer as  accepted with the ✔  rather than saying thank you.

Note that the queries will return different results if there are duplicate rows with code = 1.

You can also use a window function to verify a name has the code 1 in one of its rows:
select name, code
from (
  select name, code,
         sum(case when code = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name) code1
  from Example
) dt
where code1 > 0

Will perhaps perform better since the table is read only once.
